# Counter of words by first letter within string not working

Tags: python, string, counter

I am trying to get the counter in Python to count the words by first letter. I can get it to count everything, including spaces.

For example, in the code below, the number of words that start with 's' is 4. I know this, but my program is giving me 's' as 10, which is every 's' in the string.
How do I get this to only use the first letter in the word?

```
from collections import Counter
my_str = "When I pronounce the word Future,\n the first syllable already belongs to the past.\n\n When I pronounce the word Silence,\n I destroy it.\n\n When I pronounce the word Nothing,\n I make something no nonbeing can hold.\n\n Wislawa Szymborska"
my_count = Counter(my_str.lower())
for word in [my_str]:
    my_count[word[0].lower()]+=1
print(my_count)
```

My output is:

```
Counter({' ': 37, 'e': 21, 'n': 19, 'o': 18, 't': 13, 'i': 12, 'h': 11, 'r': 11, 's': 10, 'w': 9, '\n': 9, 'a': 9, 'l': 8, 'd': 6, 'u': 5, 'c': 5, 'p': 4, 'y': 4, 'b': 4, 'g': 4, ',': 3, '.': 3, 'm': 3, 'f': 2, 'k': 2, 'z': 1})
```

Comment: try, ``Counter(i[0].lower() for i in my_str.split())`` ?

Comment: Try using `my_str.split()` instead of `[my_str]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter
my_str = "When I pronounce the word Future,\n the first syllable already belongs to the past.\n\n When I pronounce the word Silence,\n I destroy it.\n\n When I pronounce the word Nothing,\n I make something no nonbeing can hold.\n\n Wislawa Szymborska"
my_count = Counter(map(itemgetter(0), my_str.lower().split()))
print(my_count)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'w': 7, 'i': 6, 't': 6, 'p': 4, 's': 4, 'n': 3, 'f': 2, 'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'd': 1, 'm': 1, 'c': 1, 'h': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension and `.split()`-

```
from collections import Counter
my_str = "When I pronounce the word Future,\n the first syllable already belongs to the past.\n\n When I pronounce the word Silence,\n I destroy it.\n\n When I pronounce the word Nothing,\n I make something no nonbeing can hold.\n\n Wislawa Szymborska"

my_count = Counter([i[0].lower() for i in my_str.split()])

print(my_count)
```